# Android: How to tell when a bound service has been destroyed?

Tags: android, service, serviceconnection, android-service-binding

I've got a service that's bound to from a couple of activities, each using a `ServiceConnection`.

Each activity needs to check before calling the service whether the service is already in use. So in the service I have a function (let's say `getCurrentId()` ) which returns details of what the service is currently doing.
Then in the client activity, the service connection is set up:

```
private MyService mService = null;
private ServiceConnection mConnection = new ServiceConnection() {
    public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName className, IBinder binder) {
        MyService.MyBinder myBinder = (MyService.MyBinder) binder;
        mService = myBinder.getService();
        activeId = mService.getCurrentId();
        log.i(TAG, "Service bound" );
    }
    public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName className) {
        log.i(TAG, "Service has been killed");
        mService = null;
    }
};
```

A button toggles binding to the service:

```
activity.bindService(intent, mConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
```

and unbinding:

```
activity.unbindService(mConnection);
```

I'm not calling `startService()` at all.

Before I bind to the service, I check if it's already active and what it's doing:

```
if (mService == null)
    activeId = -1;
else
    activeId = mService.getCurrentId();
```

**The problem is**, if an activity binds to and then unbinds from the service, the service `onDestroy()` method is called (I've logging in it to confirm this), which is fine. 
**BUT** this *doesn't* trigger `onServiceDisconnected()`.

So mService is never set to null, and when I get to that if statement, it happily carries on and calls `getCurrentId()`, which returns whatever the previous details were.

I gather that `onServiceDisconnected()` is only supposed to be called when the thread the service is running in is unexpectedly killed, so it's correct that it's not called when the service is destroyed due to the last activity using it unbinding.

As far as I can tell, the service isn't being reinstantiated, I've got logging throughout it.

Which gives me two questions:

Is there an alternative callback function or some way where a ServiceConnection is notified that its service has been destroyed by unbinding?

If the service *has* been destroyed, then how can I still call its functions? Or is something else going on - is the `ServiceConnection` or the `Binder` somehow returning the  value without actually calling the service?

Answer (score 0):

`onServiceDisconnected()` is only called

> when a connection to the Service has been lost. This typically happens
>   when the process hosting the service has crashed or been killed.

Quoted from the [Android docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ServiceConnection.html#onServiceDisconnected%28android.content.ComponentName%29).   This seems to be a very rare case, and will not be called when simply unbinding normally from a service.

To keep my connections with a service sane, I would suggest you bind to the service in the Activities [`onResume`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onResume%28%29) method and unbind from it in the [`onPause`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onPause%28%29) method.

Comment: onServiceDisconnected() is also called when service is destroyed (e.g. it finished its task) while activity is still bound! This is not so rare case. But when onDestroy() is called after onUnbind(), onServiceDisconnected is not called.